# Does delta hedging mimic the disposition effect?

Tags: delta-hedging, behavioral-finance

A friend of mine sent me a no-name paper on the disposition effect yesterday and asked for my opinion about it. Therein, the authors claim to have detected some evidence for a strong disposition effect in the options market where professional options traders gather.

The question i have is the following:

Given traders try to delta hedge their call position (let us ignore whether they really do it all the time for the sake of the question plz.) it means they would start unloading an existing stock position if the price rises (or increase their short position respectively).

Is it possible to infer that a) the disposition effect is an investment mistake because in a rising market you are at the wrong side of the option trade if it mimics e.g. a short option so to say? and b) does a) still hold if short sale constraints are in place? c) how to separate trading behavior due to some weird utility function from hedge trades?

Thanks a lot, happy for any discussion on this

Comment: To answer your first question: Option traders hedge in order to stabilize their pnl on the derivative, not in order to gain from the market movements. They make money from *selling* derivatives, not from having a market outlook, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, yes, i'm aware of this. However, i'm not asking why they do it but what effect it has on the findings of this paper if such trading is prevalent in the market and whether this can be shown how these two effects interplay

Comment: This is just a (very wild) guess: If you knew the open interest across strikes for each date, maybe you could guesstimate the trading share of option sellers, given some assumptions on hedging frequency etc.

Comment: Yes, thats a brilliant idea, thanks for this! I'll think about it and check by how much the results depend on the neccessary assumptions.